# Using Hash Table to count the frequencies - Self Made

Tags: arrays, algorithm, hashtable

Can I use hash table and BST for the following problems, if i am allowing extra storage O(N)?

1. Count the frequencies of all elements in an array ?
2. Finding which number is repeating maximum times in an array ?

I am mostly interested about integer elements.

Comment: This smells like homework.

Comment: What are the elements, how are they generated? integers behave differently than floating point numbers, for example.

Comment: I am only concerned about integers here .

Comment: Can you clarify what is the difference between "frequencies" and "number of occurences" in your question? (sorry if that's trivial, I am not a native English speaker)

Comment: I think both are same . Both say, how many times a element occurs

Comment: @sabithpocker this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both tasks can be done using both Hash tables and BSTs, with linear space required.

Both hash table and binary search tree can implement a map interface, where you can fast look by a key, and link it to a value.

You can use this map interface to implement a histogram, which maps from your keys to an integer.

You iterate the array, and for each element, look for it in the map (as a key). If this key exists, get the value, and increase it by one.

Otherwise, insert this new element to the map with value 1.

When this is done, you have a map fulfilling requirement 1.

To fulfill the second requirement, simply iterate the map and find the key associated with the highest value, and return it.

This is done with linear extra space needed, and is done in `O(n)` when the map is based on a hash table, and `O(nlogn)` when it's based on a BST. (all average cases, for BST, using a self balancing BST time complexity can be `O(nlogn)` worst case).

C++11 code with hash map implementing the map interface

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array[] = {1,9,9,7,5,4,1,2,0,1,0};
    std::unordered_map<int,int> histogram;
    for (int x : array) { 
        auto in_map = histogram.find(x);
        if (in_map == histogram.end()) { 
            histogram[x] = 1;
        } else { 
            ++(in_map->second);
        }
    }
    int most_occurances_element = -1;
    int most_occurances = -1;
    for (const auto& kv : histogram) {
      if (kv.second > most_occurances) {
        most_occurances_element = kv.first;
        most_occurances = kv.second;
      }
    }
    std::cout << "Most frequent element " << most_occurances_element << " with "
        << most_occurances << " occurances.";
    return 0;
}
```

Be aware that this answer refers to integers (or other enumerable types) as the elements. For floating point the answer could be completely different based on various factors (definition of "equality", source of the elements, ...)

Comment: Yes, thanks , this is a kind of explaination i was looking for.